# Delete all content on Yammer

Tags: yammer

We used to use Yammer a while back and now we're getting back on it. Problem is that most people who used it previously have left and the content left over is irrelevant today. Is there a way through an API or something to delete all content and posts on our Yammer network?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: It's intergrated on our O365 and promoted as the enterprise network.

Answer (score 2):

There are APIs which will let you delete messages (https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesid), but customers tend to just start using Yammer again. The old content disappears off the bottom. In many cases there are nuggets of info that get turned in up searches later which prove to be useful. if you want additional API help it may be best to open Support Requests with Microsoft for assistance. The main [support site](https://community.office365.com/en-us/w/yammer) is available, but you can open requests through the [O365 Admin Portal](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenkumar/archive/2013/07/18/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A bit old but still a relevant question. My organisation wanted to do this and the advice from Microsoft Premier support was:

Verified admin can choose to use the "Remove users" option under Network Admin portal. The option of "Permanently remove this user and messages" lets you remove the user and all the messages they posted (*note: This cannot be reversed).

As an alternative, for bulk deletion, the Bulk update feature, data export along with the Rest API endpoints should help achieve this. And before starting to delete the content ensure to set the data retention policy as "Hard Delete".

•   For deleting the users/files/messages/notes, use the export files' (messages.csv, files.csv and Pages.csv) which have the API URLs in it which can be called from within a powershell script for example. One will have to format and make a post request through powershell. Herewith I attached an sample script just for your reference.

(it is regarding user deletion but similar call applies)

messages.csv    api_url https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesid

files.csv   file_api_url    https://developer.yammer.com/docs/uploaded_filesid

Pages.csv   page_api_url    https://developer.yammer.com/docs/uploaded_notesid

•   For managing and removing yammer users – you could delete the users using bulk update feature. 
You could get users list by performing an export: Network Admin > Export Users and Export all users. Then perform a "Bulk Update Users" with the above spreadsheet saved as a .csv file.  Note that you'll need two columns in this spreadsheet.  The first should be titled 'Action' and the second should be titled 'Email Address' (both without the quotes).  Under action, you'll want to put 'Suspend' on every line and you'll have your users' email addresses from step 6 under 'Email Address'.

Go to Network Admin > Bulk Update Users and import that .csv file there (there's a sample Bulk Update file for reference at the page itself – it has more columns than you'll need, so just pay attention to the first two).